# How can I Auto reorder product when i choose only date of shipping in Magento frontend?

Tags: magento-1.9

Users can re-order without the effort of re-ordering. Enter the date of every month when you want the products to be shipped in Magento.

Any idea, please??

How can I use recurring profiles in Magento??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey magento by default gives recurring profile functionality,

check this answer for further details

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/640/7909