# Is Recurring profile create a new order on every billing Cycle?

Tags: sales, sales-order, reports, recurring

If i will  create an order  with recurrent profile and it is

1. `Billing Period Unit`  is `daily`
2. `Billing Frequency`  is `1`
3. `Auto Bill on Next Cycle` make `Yes`

**I have studied on this link**

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles

[Recurring Profiles - How do they work?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/489/recurring-profiles-how-do-they-work)

**But i am confuse about the thing:**

**1.** for `each billing cycle` ,is  `recurring profile create new order`?

**2.** `If not then ,is magento from second billing cycle this then this payment is not included on sales  price total`

Please help  on this issue  .I  am too confused on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the settings you listed above Magento will automatically create a new order each day and charge the customer.

Comment: Can you please tell me which magento cronjob function do this

Answer (score 1):

Recurring Profile(beta) is a great feature in Magento to bill customer on frequency like daily,monthly,yearly basis.
So you can check magento core module `Mage_Payment` in that `Model/Recurring/Profile.php` and you can also look at in `Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php`

In this file you can look at `prepareProductRecurringProfileOptions()` method.
So here funda for recurring profile is when ever customer is subscribed for daily,weekly,monthly,yearly it will call two API call that are

1. deduct initial fee amount
2. deduct subscription amount

for best understanding follow this link:
http://www.blog.modulesgarden.com/recurring-payments-in-magento/

I hope it will help you !