# what are some approach to setup a monthly bill system?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, extensions, billing

I'm interested in setting up a monthly billing system for my business customers.

I've already setup my site to checkout if you're a business without the need of a credit card to pay upfront. I then have to manually export all order information for each company's bill at the end of each month and generate a bill for them to pay (similar to a phone bill).

What i want is a system that will auto generate a customer's pdf/.jpeg bill based on the customer group that is set. After the bill is generated, it is then automatically emailed to the customer. this is then repeated every 30 days.

Is there an extension that already does this? as i wasnt able to find any. If not, what is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a recurring profile, something already present in Magento. See [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/489/recurring-profiles-how-do-they-work) post for some more info and maybe delete this post later.

Comment: but isnt recurring profile for subscriptions? to setup a set amount to be charged to a client each month.

Comment: Yes. That is what you described in your post.

Comment: Actually no, subscription allows you to subscribe to a product and pay for it each month. What i have done is to allow my business customers to buy what they need without paying upfront (not subscription), then i generate a printout of everything they ordered with the total they need to pay. similar to a Telephone bill, electricity bill, etc.

Comment: @Nxlevel I know this is old, but did you ever find a solution? I'm currently looking for a module that would do what you are asking for. Thanks

Comment: @JonathanPellerin no I didn't. I didn't have the time to focus on this bit I'm still interested in a solution. Do you code? Would you like to collaborate?

Comment: @Nxlevel Yes I do code. This feature will be very important to us since it's gonna become the backbone of our business. I'm open to collaboration.

Comment: @jonathanpellerin Ok great! I created a temp email maddsickk(at)gmail.com message me and we can exchange contacts and go from there.

Comment: @Nxlevel I sent an email to that address. Thanks

Comment: Great! I just responded. Will provide my details and do away with this address