# Magento subscribe for the products?

Tags: magento-1.9

any idea about or any extension available for the products subscription in magento. for example if a customer if a customer subscribe for some specific product he can get that product from the store with regular intervals in the year ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default magento provide a `Recurring Profile` for product subscription. It's too long to explain in details ,But you can get more idea about this from below links.

- [Link1](http://www.magedevelopers.com/blog/magento-payments-gateways/recurring-profiles-in-magento/)
- [Link2](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-recurring-profile.html)
- [Link3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/489/recurring-profiles-how-do-they-work)
- [Link4](http://hubpages.com/technology/Effectively-Working-with-Recurring-Profiles-in-Magento)