# Magento Recurring Profiles Error

Tags: magento-1.9, recurring

I'm testing the Magento Recurring Profiles feature as we'd like to do a monthly subscription box (like the BarkBox or HelloFresh).  Anyway, when I place the order for it I get the following error:

```
Unable to load the order.
Trace:
#0 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include()
#1 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#2 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#3 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#4 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#5 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#6 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('before_body_end', true)
#8 /home/site/public_site/app/design/frontend/default/jm_summer/template/page/1column.phtml(230): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('before_body_end')
#9 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/site...')
#10 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#11 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#15 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(295): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#16 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->successAction()
#17 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('success')
#18 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/site/public_site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/site/public_site/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/site/public_site/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Everything ran through PayPal and was working fine up until the confirmation/success page.  Can anyone offer any insight or help?  TIA!

Comment: You Can Refer Below Link for Recurring Profiles Error :http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/489/recurring-profiles-how-do-they-work

Comment: I read through all of that before but it doesn't answer my question.  The order is charged but never shows up in Magento.